# actix web Data with mutable content

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using Actix web and created a service that modifies some of its values. So some functions are using `&mut self`which causes this error. This service is added to main with app_data(Data::new(Service)). How can I fix that error?

I put an example of the problem below.

```
rustc: cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable
trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `std::sync::Arc<
???
```

```
pub struct Test {
    pub val: String,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn change(&mut self) {
        self.val = "new".to_string()
    }
}

async fn test(test: Data<Test>) -> Result<HttpResponse, ApiError>{
    test.change();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().finish();
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping your state in `Mutex`.

Comment: Does the Mutex need to have async support?

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping it in a Mutex worked.

```
async fn test(test: Data<Mutex<Test>>) -> Result<HttpResponse, ApiError>{
    test.lock().map_err(ApiError::read_error)?.change();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().finish();
}
```